# hibernate @SQLInsert call stored procedure error

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I want to insert data into entity via stored procedure that was created in Oracle.The stored procedure is not a very complex one. When I try to insert data in normally,it works.But when I use @SQLInsert to call stored procedure,it gives me error like that:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ora-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Due to this error,seems problem with the date parameter.But if problem occurs due to date parameter,why I could insert data in normally.

That is the entity;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_USER")
@XmlRootElement
@SQLInsert(
        sql="call      PROC_ADD_USER(:P_ID,:P_USER_NAME,:P_PASSWORD,:P_NAME,:P_SURNAME,:P_LOGIN_DATE)",
        callable=true)
    public class User implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="USER_ID")
        private String userId;

        @Column(name="USER_NAME")        
        private String userName;

        @Column(name="PASSWORD") 
        private String password;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="SURNAME")
        private String surname;

        @Column(name="LOGIN_DATE")
        @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date loginDate;
```

That is the code for saving User:

```
    Session session =((EntityManagerImpl) entityManager.getDelegate()).getSession();
    User user=new User();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("user name1");
    user.setPassword("password1");
    user.setName("name1");
    user.setSurname("surname 1");

    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    user.setLoginDate(utilDate);
    Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);
            transaction.commit();
 } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();
        } finally {
            //session.close();
        }
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: How is the `LOGIN_DATE` column defined in the database? And how do you know the error is related to the `loginDate` field and not the others?

Comment: LOGIN_DATE column is DATE type.I googled about ora-01858 error and this error occurs due to date type(acording to them I think it can be error like that).